# How do i use Aiohttp with PyPac

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

At my work the system won't let us make http requests without using a proxy. However the proxy is found through creating a pypac session.

How can I use this pypac session inside an aiohttp session to make async requests?

Answer (score 1):

So, I've found the answer is to use the pypac session to get a proxy which you can then put into the aiohttp request:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import re
from pypac import PACSession, get_pac

pac = get_pac(url="https://somewebaddress.pac")
pac_session = PACSession(pac)

async def _fetch_async(session, url, proxy:bool=False):
    #Get the proxy for this url
    if proxy:
        proxies = pac_session \
            ._get_proxy_resolver(pac) \
            .get_proxy_for_requests(url)
        match = re.search("^(\w*)", str(url))
        proxy = proxies[match.group()]
    else:
        proxy = None
    #Fetch with aiohttp session
    async with session.request("get", url, proxy=proxy) as resp:
        return resp

async def _fetch_all_async(urls):
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(
                _fetch_async(
                    session,
                    url
                    )
                )
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def request_all(self, urls:list=[]):
    #Start the loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    #Gaher tasks and run
    coro = _fetch_all_async(urls)
    resps = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    return resps
```

Hope this helps any fellow sufferers.